# Merge 2 columns to a new column in txt file using Python

Tags: python

Helllo everyone, here is my txt file, I want to merge the first column and the second column to a new column, I tried to change the File extension to Excel, and use the `concatenate`command, but there are over 1000000 datas and the excel can only show the limited quantity, thus I will lost some datas. So I want to ask you professinal people wether there is a method in Python to merge 2 columns directly in txt file without format converting?

```
Datum       Zeit        W [cm]      Status      DT-Index    W [mNHN]    
01/05/2016  00:01:00    313,000000  U   42491,000694    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:02:00    313,000000  U   42491,001389    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:03:00    313,000000  U   42491,002083    -1,87   
01/05/2016  00:04:00    313,000000  U   42491,002778    -1,87   
...... # over 1000000 datas
```

what I want:

```
Datum       Zeit        W [cm]      Status      DT-Index    W [mNHN]    Datetime
01/05/2016  00:01:00    313,000000  U   42491,000694    -1,87       01/05/2016/00:01:00 
01/05/2016  00:02:00    313,000000  U   42491,001389    -1,87       01/05/2016/00:02:00     
01/05/2016  00:03:00    313,000000  U   42491,002083    -1,87       01/05/2016/00:03:00 
01/05/2016  00:04:00    313,000000  U   42491,002778    -1,87       01/05/2016/00:04:00 
...... #over 1000000 datas
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas library to do this, should be relatively straightforward

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/your_csv.csv", sep="\t")
df["Datetime"] = df["Datum"] + "/" + df["Zeit"]
```

Although worth saying you can do some more sophisticated things with datetime formats which might suit your use case better

Comment: Thanks for your replying, but do I need to `write datetime` or something else? And here is the error
  `File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Datum'`

Comment: Looks like you csv might not be reading in properly, you can try the parameter `sep="\t"` if your file is tab delimited (since you have commas in your data values)

Comment: Still the same error.
  `File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Datum'` Do I need to add some command about the datetime format? like: `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d.%m.%Y/%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: What that error means is that it can't find the column "Datum" in the DataFrame. That's likely to be caused by it not being read in correctly (or maybe there are spaces in your column names). Without having the data it's hard for me to say why. But you can type `print(df.columns)` to see the names of the columns that have been loaded in, which might give you a clue.

Comment: The datas can not be printed, and I think the whole column can not be read, the error is still the same as before.

Comment: The data has been read in by the looks of it, otherwise it would error on the `read_csv` line. The error you are showing is from trying to index the dataframe when it can't find the column name "Datum" i.e. `df["Datum"]` is causing the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180725/discussion-between-sven-h-and-its-nele).